# GoogleAppsScript（GAS）を用いて、共有しているスプレッドシートにアクセス中のアカウント全てを対象に、メッセージボックスを表示させたいです。

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

１名を編集者として共有しているスプレッドシートがあります。
このスプレッドシートにはGoogleAppsScript（GAS）を設定しております。

```
function myFunction() {
  Browser.msgBox("Hello World");
}
```

上記スクリプトを実行すると、
このスクリプトを作成したGoogleアカウントはこのスプレッドシート上に”Hello World”と表示されます。
このスクリプトを作成していない、このスプレッドシートを共有された編集者Googleアカウントでは、
このスプレッドシートを開いていても何も表示されません。

共有先のGoogleアカウントにも、”Hello World”を表示させるような設定方法はあるのでしょうか...？
無知でお恥ずかしいのですが、ご回答いただけますと大変助かります。

Comment: こちら別案で対応しました。
共有先Googleアカウントに対して、時刻指定のトリガーでメッセージボックスを表示することはできませんでした。
スプレッドシートを起動時にメッセージボックスを表示させる設定を施したところ、共有先Googleアカウントにもメッセージボックスが表示されましたので、この策で対応しました。